# Route Locally generated packets to different gateway

Tags: iptables, routing, iproute

I need to send the packets of specific port to different gateway.  This is the situation:

The server has different services, like http, dns, and mail (smtp,pop,imap), and it has two gateways.

eth2:  Gateway1 (Default gw)

ppp0:  Gateway2

All the services run ok on the default gw (eth2), but I need to send all the packets that the server generate to send email (dest port 25) to go out to the Gateway2 (ppp0).

It isn´t possible with prerouting because there are packets that are locally generated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could control DNS and SMTP at least by installing specific routes. You could put in a route for the SMTP's "smart server" or mail relay, and the "nameserver" IP address using `ip`. You'd have to know the PPP IP address on the inside however. Supposing you use Google's public DNS server, and ppp0 has IP address 10.0.0.1:

```
ip route add 8.8.8.8 via 10.0.0.1
```

That would install a "static route" to Google's public DNS via the PPP IP address. You cold do the same with your mail relay(s).